# TMPro not found in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, tmp

I'm using `Visual Studio Code` to write my code for Unity.
The following extension I've added to Visual Studio Code:
C#, Debugger for Unity, Unity Code Snippets & Unity Tools

Using TMPro to work with TextMeshPro components throws me this error:

```
Unnecessary using directive. [Assembly-CSharp]csharp(CS8019)
The type or namespace name 'TMPro' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [Assembly-CSharp, Assembly-CSharp, Assembly-CSharp, Assembly-CSharp, Assembly-CSharp, Assembly-CSharp, Assembly-CSharp]csharp(CS0246)
```

On the bright-side, in `Unity Editor` no errors are thrown, but it is still annoying.

Does anybody know if there's an additional Extension I have to download or how to fix this issue?

Best

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have had this for ages, here is the solution for Unity 2021.1 and latest Vscode plugin:

Go to preferences>External tools and Untick everything (all generate csproj tickboxes)
delete all the sln and CSproj files.

Hit Regenerate project files.

Comment: Great . This one worked for me . Thanks buddy

Comment: Nope. doesn't work. Or, the instructions above are not thorough enough. Didn't work in Unity 2021.3.12f1. TMPro obtained through packages not asset store.

Comment: actually it did help als ofor v 2021.3. and did not require to restart , delete library files, or uninstall anything

Answer (score 12):

I ran into this problem after I had set up unit tests within Unity.  If you have an assembly definition file in your Unity project then it needs a new Assembly Definition Reference added in the inspector.  In this case, `Unity.TextMeshPro`.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29953910)

Comment: This fixed the issue I encountered where Unity and Rider (IDE) wouldn't stop raising an error (Not in runtime, couldn't run the scene) on TMPro not being found.

I indeed needed to add Unity.TextMeshPro.asmdef to the asmdef file the project was using to reference the assembly definitions. Thank you.

If you imported TextMeshPro in your project, search in the Project explorer for Unity.TextMeshPro to find it.

Comment: It was exact my case and it worked! Thx.

Answer (score 5):

If you have moved your project into a different folder, be sure to update `Assembly-CSharp.csproj` to have the new, correct filepaths for libraries like `TextMeshPro` and `UnityEngine.UI`.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I had to add a [script assembly](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompilationAssemblyDefinitionFiles.html) to my "Scripts" folder (where I keep all my scripts for a game). Once that was done I added a reference in "Assembly Definition References" and selected "Unity.TextMeshPro" then I could add `using TMPro;` to my script.

This didn't used to happen and I suspect it's the Test Runner complaining because it doesn't know what "TMPro" is.

[image: unity3d assembly reference for TextMeshPro]

Comment: doesn't work. I just tried this. TMP was imported via package manager, and unity version is 2021.3.12f1. also, you might want to mention you need to add assembly definitions for the other imported projects too. Not that this works.

Comment: @ericfrazer I tried to be transparent about that fact that I found myself in a non-standard scenario due to the exact circumstances you just mentioned. cheers~

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the issue was that within the *.sln file of my project the references were not found due to the lack of the path to the *.dll file.

Deleting `Unity.TextMeshPro` and `Unity.TextMeshPro.Editor` and then re-importing them solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks. I have a fresh install of Unity 2020.3.18f1 and my first use of a TMPro UI element had this issue when I attempted to access the obj.text element in a script. Uninstalling the TMPro asset package and reinstalling it, seems to have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Open the `Package Manager` and make sure you installed the TextMeshPro package.
If this error persists, restart the `Unity Editor`.

Comment: Hey Thanks for the answer.

The error doesn't occur in `Unity Editor` but in `Visual Studio Code`.

Comment: useless answer. why did you spend the time to type that.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the answer was to delete all the project files, reinstall TMPro in the package manager, and delete all the folders at Library/PackageCache/

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that worked for me. I hope it helps.

(in unity) > window > TextMeshPro >
*import TMP essential resources
*import TMP examples and extras